# Why is [x, 5-2x] not a vector subspace of R^2?

Tags: vector-spaces

For my homework there is a problem asking to show if [x, 5-2x] is or is not a vector subspace of R^2. I am having a lot of trouble understanding why this specific set is not a subset of R^2 as it seems to follow both scalar and addition rules the same way as any other R^2 subset would.

a([x, 5-2x]) + b([y, 5-2y])

= [ax, a5-a2x] + [by, b5-b2y]

= [ax + by, (a5-a2x) + (b5-b2y)] which seems to be a subset of R^2?

Am I misunderstanding how to tell if the set is a subset or not?
I know that it is not a subset due to the answer on the back of the book telling me that it is not.

Comment: You mean a vectorial subspace ? In that case $(0,0)$ do not belong.

Comment: Hello @zwim, yes I do mean vectorial subspace. Could you clarify why (0, 0) does not belong? If plugged in, it would yield [0, 5(a+b)] in which case both 0 and 5(a+b) should be real numbers, no?

Comment: For $(0,0)$ to be contained, there needs to be a solution to the system $x = 0$ and $5 - 2x = 0$, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, this clears up why this set is not a vector subspace for me, but I am still confused as to why the solutions of (0,0) is required for this to qualify as a vector subspace or R^2? doesn't being a subscpace inherently imply that it does not hold ALL of the same values as R^2? and if so why is (0, 0) a requirement? Sorry if this is somehow obvious, I am somewhat struggling to understand this topic.

Comment: Take a look at your definition of a vector space! It has to contain a zero - element, and since a subspace needs to be a vector space by itself, it needs to contain a zero - element, in this case $(0,0)$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your help. I feel that I understand the topic a lot better now.

Comment: If you plot some points $(x,5-2x)$ for different values of $x$, you will see they are aligned on a line **which doesn't pass throughout the origin**. In this case we say that we have an affine line which is not a vector subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this set $S = \{[x,5-2x]; x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is not closed under multiplication by a scalar. The vector $[1,3]$ is in $S$ but $[2,6]$ is not, as clearly $6 \not = 5-2×2$.

In particular, you made mistakes in your arithmetic verifying that $S$ is closed under addition. Let $X=[x,5-2x]$ and $Y=[y,5-2y]$ be any $2$ elements in $S$. Then for $S$ to be closed under addition, the sum $X+Y =$ $[x+y, (5-2x) + (5-2y)]$ $=[(x+y), 10-2(x+y)]$ must be in $S$ for any such $X$ and $Y$, which would imply that $10-2(x+y)$ must equal $5-(x+y)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. But what about say $X =[3,-1]$ i.e., $x=3$ and $Y=[4,-3]$ i.e., $y=4$.